# Testing validity of an instrumental variable with exact identification

Tags: instrumental-variables, validity

I am conducting an instrumental variable regression. I have one endogenous variable and one instrument? How can I test if the instrument is valid? What I have done for now is run the ivreg command and got the residuals and regressed those on the instrument (along with other exogenous regressors) and they are uncorrelated. I tried finding help online but everything seems to be for overidentifying restrictions. I have exact identification.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you be more clear about testing the validity of an instrumental variable. Surely you are aware that the exclusion restriction in a just-identified case is fundamentally untestable. So what exactly do you want to test for, weak instruments?

Comment: Hi - yes exclusion restriction cannot be tested. I already have the relevancy condition tested for. When I said validity I meant something 'akin' to the exclusion restriction but for a just-identified case. I tried another method (which is also used for overidentifcation) wherein I do the 2sls regression and use residuals from this and regress it on the instrument (I think this is the sargan test - for overid). I basically want to know if there is any way to test whether the instrument has no direct relationship with the DV - or is this a theoretical assumption to make?

Comment: Hi Aishwarya, yes this is essentially a structural assumption you need to make. In the over-identified cased the Sargan test that you suggested is one way to build evidence for exclusion but this cannot be done in the just-identified case because you lack the added information of extra instruments.

Comment: Thank you very much :)